# Setting timeout in Resteasy, JAX-RS

Tags: jboss, timeout, resteasy

I have some HTTP calls that are very long lasting and I need the results.

How do I extend the timeout on the serverside for these types of calls. **Note** this is not `Session-Timeout` as defined in the `web.xml` for the server.

I noticed JAX-RS has an `@Timeout` notation, but I don't know how to use it, or if it even works with this type of configuration.

My calls are setup like so:

```
@Path("/path/")
public class BulkCreate {
    @Path("/path")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response query(@QueryParam("token") String token,
            BulkCreateObject[] objects) {
          ....
        }
}
```

I can't use [@Suspend](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html) or make them totally asynchronous.

I didn't start setting up this project so I don't know what other items are necessary to enable these interfaces, except that they work, but I can't figure out where to set an extended timeout.

I set the timeout on the client-request to a very long time, but the request still times out (I believe on the server-side) and throws a "Timeout Exception" back to the client after ~2-3 minutes?

I can't find anything in the docs [here](http://resteasy.jboss.org/docs).